# Can I fit a VAR model using the LASSO method in Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, lasso-regression

I have to fit 40 time series in a VectorAutoregressive model, the enormous quantity of variables suggest to use a selection method. I would love to use the LASSO method, but I'm using statsmodel for the fitting, and the only way to implement LASSO with that library is for a Linear regression model. Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [fit_regularized](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html), it's like when you fit an OLS, and you set L1_wt to be 1 so that it is a lasso:

```
sm.OLS(..,..).fit_regularized(alpha=..,L1_wt=1)
```

We can with an example, first load the boston dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

scaler = StandardScaler()
data = load_boston()
data_scaled  = scaler.fit_transform(data.data)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_scaled, data.target, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Below to show that it works similarly, and you need to tweak the shrinkage parameter, alpha anyway in your model:

```
alphas = [0.0001,0.001, 0.01, 0.1,0.2, 0.5, 1]
mse_sklearn = []
mse_sm = []

for a in alphas:

    clf     = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=a)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    mse_sklearn.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))

    mdl = sm.OLS(y_train,sm.add_constant(X_train)).fit_regularized(alpha=a,L1_wt=1)
    y_pred = mdl.predict(sm.add_constant(X_test))
    mse_sm.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

Visualize the results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(alphas,mse_sm,label="sm")
ax.plot(alphas,mse_sklearn,label="sklearn")
ax.legend()
```

[image]